# .NET Core Expression DbFunctions DiffDays

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, dbfunctions

I have an extension I have written for the date filter using the DiffDays method with .NET.
In .NET Core, EF.Functions was replaced by DbFunctions, so it could not execute it.

My .NET Code

```
 private static (ParameterExpression param, MemberExpression prop) QueryExpressions<Entity>(IQueryable<Entity> query, string property)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "x");
            MemberExpression prop;

            if (property.Contains('.'))
            {
                string[] childProperties = property.Split('.');

                prop = Expression.Property(param, childProperties[0]);

                for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
                    prop = Expression.Property(prop, childProperties[i]);
            }
            else
                prop = Expression.Property(param, property);

            return (param, prop);
        }

 public static IQueryable<Entity> DiffDaysLessThan<Entity>(this IQueryable<Entity> query, string property, object value)
        {
            var methodInfo = typeof(DbFunctions).GetMethod("DiffDays", new Type[] { typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTime?) });

            (ParameterExpression param, MemberExpression prop) = QueryExpressions(query, property);

            var left = Expression.Call(
                methodInfo,
                Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), typeof(DateTime?)), Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(DateTime?)));
            var right = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0), typeof(int?));

            var body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);

            return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(body, param));
        }
```

**.NET CORE**

```
   public static IQueryable<Entity> DiffDaysLessThan<Entity>(this IQueryable<Entity> query, string property, object value)
        {

            var methodInfo = typeof(SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("DateDiffSecond", new Type[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(DateTime?) });

            (ParameterExpression param, MemberExpression prop) = QueryExpressions(query, property);

            var left = Expression.Call(
                methodInfo,
                Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), typeof(DateTime?)), Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(DateTime?)));
            var right = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(0), typeof(int?));

            var body = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);

            return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(body, param));
        }
```

I could not equals the typeof (DbFunctions) parameter on the Expression.Call side when calling the method.

**ERROR**

> System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiffSecond(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' (Parameter 'method')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core functions are *extension* methods of `DbFunctions` class returned by `EF.Functions` property. So although unused, you have to pass the first argument of type `DbFunctions` when calling them, e.g.

```
var left = Expression.Call(
    methodInfo,
    Expression.Constant(EF.Functions, typeof(DbFunctions)), // <--
    Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), typeof(DateTime?)),
    Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(DateTime?)));
```

Comment: I would come to say I have solved it using "Expression.Constant (EF.Functions)" and I saw your answer. :D
I have also tried without typing “typeof(DbFunctions)“, it is working, but I guess your solution is much better. Thanks